# Convert chan to non chan in golang

Tags: go, type-conversion, channel

Is it possible to let function `funcWithNonChanResult` have the following interface:

```
func funcWithNonChanResult() int {
```

And if I want it to use function `funcWithChanResult` with the interface:

```
func funcWithChanResult() chan int {
```

In other words, can I somehow convert `chan int` to `int`? Or I must have `chan int` result type in all the functions which use `funcWithChanResult`?

Currently, I tried these methods:

```
result = funcWithChanResult() 
//  cannot use funcWithChanResult() (type chan int) as type int in assignment


result <- funcWithChanResult() 
// invalid operation: result <- funcWithChanResult() (send to non-chan type int)
```

Full code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func getIntSlowly() int {
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
    return 123
}

func funcWithChanResult() chan int {
    chanint := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        chanint <- getIntSlowly()
    }()
    return chanint
}

func funcWithNonChanResult() int {
    var result int
    result = funcWithChanResult() 
    // result <- funcWithChanResult() 
    return result
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Received first int:", <-funcWithChanResult())
    fmt.Println("Received second int:", funcWithNonChanResult())
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/zFFZV0pR07)

Comment: Go is statically typed and you cannot do strange magic. A `chan int` is not an `int` just like a `func(map[float64]bool) complex128` is not an `int`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `chan int` is a channel of `int` values, it is not a single `int` value but a source of `int` values (or also a target, but in your case you use it as source).

So therefore you can't convert `chan int` to `int`. What you can do and probably what you mean is use a value (of type `int`) received from a `chan int` as an `int` value.

This is not a problem:

```
var result int
ch := funcWithChanResult()
result = <- ch
```

Or more compact:

```
result := <- funcWithChanResult()
```

Combine this with the `return` statement:

```
func funcWithNonChanResult() int {
    return <-funcWithChanResult()
}
```

Output (as expected):

```
Received first int: 123
Received second int: 123
```

Try your modified, working example on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/J48w5j0zdw).