# Iterating over multiple returns in golang

Tags: go, multiple-return-values

I am trying to take input from a text file containing domains(unknown amount) to then use each as an argument and get their server type. As expected, this only returns the last domain. How do I iterating multiple return values? 
Below is the code.
    // Test
    package main

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "time"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    //"github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

var Domain string
var Target string

func main() {
    Domain := DomainGrab()
    Target := BannerGrab(Domain)
    //CheckDB if not listed then add else skip
    //RiskDB
    //Email
    fmt.Println(Domain)
    fmt.Println(Target)
}

func BannerGrab(s string) string {

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", s, nil)
    if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Authac/0.1")
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    serverEntry := resp.Header.Get("Server")
    return serverEntry

}
func DomainGrab() string {

    //c := colly.NewCollector()
// Open the file.
    f, _ := os.Open("domains.txt")
    defer f.Close()
    // Create a new Scanner for the file.
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    // Loop over all lines in the file and print them.
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Text()
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        //fmt.Println(line)
        return line
    }
    return Domain
}
```

Comment: There's no concurrency here and therefore absolutely no reason to use a channel. Just return a slice of values.

Comment: You're calling `return` unconditionally within your scanner loop.  It's never going to loop more than once, it's just going to scan the first item, sleep for 2 seconds, and then return that first item and discard the rest.

Comment: Please, please _DON'T PANIC_. that `check` function is not idiomatic golang _at all_

Comment: @Kaedys And this is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: @Adrian In the long term, their will be concurrency. But, I will attempt to use slices to fix this. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem that type of check function is fairly commonly used in the "hacking" phase of putting code together, or in scripts that really should just die if an error occurs.  And to be honest, if I want to kill an app, I _vastly_ prefer `panic()` to `log.Fatal()` or `os.Exit(1)`, because panics can be caught, and they run deferred calls and such before they die.

Comment: @Kaedys: `panic`'s can't be caught, there's a `recover` mechanism. You really shouldn't think of panics as exceptiosn. The term _"caught"_ suggests you are treating them as exceptions. A `panic` should be used in rare occasions, where something completely left-field has happened. The last thing you want in those cases is for a deferred call to be invoked. It might attempt to close a resource that doesn't exist (yet) etc...

Comment: I meant "caught" in the sense of recovery, yes.  I use it specifically as a replacement for os.Exit or log.Fatal, _not_ a replacement for proper error return and handling, and I use it as a replacement for those because unlike os.Exit or log.Fatal (which calls os.Exit), a panic can be intercepted via `recover()` before the program terminates, while os.Exit cannot.  And whether a defer runs things it shouldn't or not is purely on the engineer coding them.  A defer to clean up something should _not_ be made before that something is there to clean up.

Comment: Defers by design run when the function returns regardless of how it does so.  So you should never ever schedule a deferred call unless you're at a point in the function where running that call will _always_ be the correct thing to do at the end of the function regardless of how the function returns.  Cleaning up something that doesn't exist yet does not fit that requirement, and thus reflects a code design error, not a problem with using `panic` or `defer`.

Comment: Is it possible that system that control domain names in file will push data to you directly? This is the end scenario. Their will be a function pushing domain names directly to me. (GO-Colly) But, I can't capture the domains crawled using [ e.Request.Visit(e.Attr("href")) ] <-- Requires basic understanding of Go-Colly.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You are correct and I do see what you mean now: I've updated the code. Still unsure how to go about what I am trying to do here though.  A Function will push a domain the one described in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do it "concurrently", you would return a channel through which you will send the multiple things you want to return:

https://play.golang.org/p/iYBGPwfYLYR

```
func DomainGrab() <-chan string {
    ch := make(chan string, 1)
    f, _ := os.Open("domains.txt")
    defer f.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    go func() {
    // Loop over all lines in the file and print them.
        for scanner.Scan() {
            line := scanner.Text()
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
            ch <- line
        }
        close(ch)
    }()
    return ch
}
```

Comment: Unless said file is enormous, this pattern makes little sense (and OP said it's 3 lines long). You want to read in the file and get it closed. Returning a slice is far more pragmatic and you could use it concurrently from there

Comment: OP also said the file is 3 sites but will expand as it visits more sites.  If they read the file and close it, they obviously won't be able to read new lines as they get added.

Comment: Makes sense... but not to argue (sorry), but then it would make even more sense to read the entire file of original entries, close the file, then modify it as necessary, or even write to a different file. Leaving the file open might not be the best approach, especially with concurrent r/w access.

Comment: Yes. The file will concurrently expand. For the sake of the CURRENT issue at hand. Iterating through the domains.txt with 3 SITES in it is the issue. I've also realized using this code will not pass EACH domain into the next function due to the type so a conversion will be necessary.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear Your the second to suggest slices. I will be attempting this right now.

Comment: I am attempting to use this example but the channel itself is of TYPE Chan String. When attempting to use StackOverflow examples to convert, it's returning errors that seems to be pointing to ALL of the stored information and not iterating one of each to be used as an argument in the bannergrab function. Example I Used(and adjusted): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860644/convert-chan-to-non-chan-in-golang

Comment: Also, I did adjust BannerGrab to accept Chan Strings but still can't be used in a http request. I'd hate to constantly creating new questions. What is the best way to solve this issue or convert Chan Strings to string so that it can't be used in the http request. Side Note: I am still not sure if this will iterate through each word of the text file. I do understand by definition it should.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to read the file, somehow detect that file was modified and have a method that will emit these modifications to client code.

That is not how files work.

you have two options:

1. Listen for file changes using some OS specific API - https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/linux-filesystem-events-inotify
2. Read file using infinite loop. Read the file once. Save the copy into memory.  Read the same file again and again in loop till new file is different from copy and calculate the delta.

Check if that is possible to use `push` instead of `pull` for getting new domains. Is it possible that system that control domain names in file will push data to you directly?

If `loop` is the only possible option, set up some pause time between file reads to reduce system load.

Use channels as @dave [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53306394/1420332) when you managed to get new domains and need to process them concurrently.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I made that conclusion from these statements `take input from a text file containing domains` and `since the domain list ... will CONCURRENTLY expand`. Hopefully author can clarify.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. The main issue is returning EACH WORD in the text file to be passed as an argument for the next function to use. I've been able to return ALL which results in error or just ONE which doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Authac No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the BEST solution. But, I decided to get rid of a separate function all together just cover more ground. I'll post below the code of what I expect. Now, I need to parse the domains so that Root URL's and Subdomains are only scanned once.

```
// Main
package main

import (
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

//var Domain string
var Target string


func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector()

    c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
        fmt.Println("Request URL:", r.Request.URL, "\n Failed with response:", r.StatusCode)
    })

    // Find and visit all links
    c.OnHTML("a", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        e.Request.Visit(e.Attr("href"))
    })

    c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
        Domain := r.URL.String()
        Target := BannerGrab(Domain)
        fmt.Println(Domain)
        fmt.Println(Target)
        fmt.Println("Dropping By.. ", r.URL)
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    })

    c.Visit("http://www.milliondollarhomepage.com/")
    }

    //CheckDB if not listed else add
    //RiskDB
    //Email


func BannerGrab(s string) string {

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", s, nil)
        if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Authac/0.1")
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    serverEntry := resp.Header.Get("Server")
    return serverEntry

}
```